# How to make .val().toLowerCase() work properly?

Tags: jquery, if-statement, input

I am having a hard time trying to show errors with jquery. I want to confirm a email input by the user. Basically, if the user doesn't fill in the fields correctly, I want the error to show.

I want the user to fill in both fields with the same input text. If the user doesn't, I want to show the error "emails are not the same" under the "email_confirm" input. If they are, I want to hide this error.

Here is a fiddle I made:
http://jsfiddle.net/5ZjwW/1/

This is my jquery code:

```
 $("#email").blur(function ()
{
    if ($("#email").val() == "")
    {
        $("#err1_email").removeClass("hidden");
        $("#err2_email").addClass("hidden");
    }
    else
    {
        $("#err1_email").addClass("hidden");
        if (!emailregex.test($('#email').val()))
        {
            $("#err2_email").removeClass("hidden");
        }
        else
        {
            $("#err2_email").addClass("hidden");
        }
    }
})
$("#email_confirm").blur(function ()
    {
        if ($("#email_confirm").val() == "")
        {
            $("#err1_confirmemail").removeClass("hidden");
        }
        else
        {
            $("#err1_confirmemail").addClass("hidden");
            if ($("email_confirm").val().toLowerCase() != $("email").val().toLowerCase())
            {
                $("#err2_confirmemail").removeClass("hidden");
            }
            else
            {
                $("#err2_confirmemail").addClass("hidden");
            }
        }
    })
```

Thank you very much.

Comment: Look in the [JavaScript error console](http://www.netmagazine.com/tutorials/javascript-debugging-beginners) and tell what errors you see there and which lines they point to.

Comment: `emailregex` is not defined in your fiddle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You miss some `#` in your selectors, so they are not selecting anything; try:

```
if ($("#email_confirm").val().toLowerCase() != $("#email").val().toLowerCase())
```

In the fiddle is missing `emailregex`

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/5ZjwW/2/

Comment: Thank you! I can't believe I hadn't seen it. I guess that means i'm getting tired! For the regex, it works fine with the whole code.

Answer (score 1):

your id selectors are missing the prefix `#` in the ` if condition

```
if ($("#email_confirm").val().toLowerCase() != $("#email").val().toLowerCase())
```

also the `emailregex` is missing

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/aMPTv/)